# Custom transitions between view controllers supporting different/mismatching orientations

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

Specifically, I have a problem with dismissing view controller B so that view controller A is visible again. Following the steps below, the appearance of view controller A will be heavily distorted.

- View controller A supports ***all orientations but upside down***.
- View controller B supports ***portrait only***.

How to cause the problem/bug.

1. Hold VC A in portrait.
2. Open VC B.
3. Hold device in landscape.
4. Dismiss VC B.

The appearance of VC A is now heavily broken/distorted/buggy.

I am suspecting the same problem would appear if the VCs support another set of orientations, but for now this is the exact and simple case where the problem occurs.

The transition is handled by a class implementing `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. It basically looks like this.

```
class FadeAnimator: NSObject {
    let duration: TimeInterval = 1.0
    var originFrame = CGRect.zero
}

extension FadeAnimator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return self.duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

        containerView.addSubview(toView)
        toView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.duration, animations: {
            toView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }
}
```

Full sample project which shows the problem is here: https://bitbucket.org/zzzzapjonny/testtransition/src/master/testtransition/